# Fraction object doesn't have __int__ but int(Fraction(...)) still works

Tags: python, int, fractions, python-internals

In Python, when you have an object you can convert it to an integer using the `int` function.

For example `int(1.3)` will return `1`. This works internally by using the `__int__` magic method of the object, in this particular case `float.__int__`.

In Python `Fraction` objects can be used to construct exact fractions.

```
from fractions import Fraction
x = Fraction(4, 3)
```

`Fraction` objects lack an `__int__` method, but you can still call `int()` on them and get a sensible integer back. I was wondering how this was possible with no `__int__` method being defined.

```
In [38]: x = Fraction(4, 3)

In [39]: int(x)
Out[39]: 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__trunc__` method is used.

```
>>> class X(object):
    def __trunc__(self):
        return 2.


>>> int(X())
2
```

`__float__`  does not work

```
>>> class X(object):
    def __float__(self):
        return 2.

>>> int(X())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    int(X())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'X'
```

[The CPython source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/79397a76d2b1/Objects/abstract.c#l1283) shows when `__trunc__` is used.

Comment: A friend of mine has found a link to the CPython source that shows when `__trunc__` comes in. I'm going to edit it into your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Interesting thing this is not anywhere in the Python docs - instead, the only reference to it is on PEP 3141: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/